# Display results in 2 columns in one div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have problem with displaying children in a parent div.

Here is my source:  **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qigax/3/edit)**

This items are collapsible panels. When all of them are collapsed, it works great, but try to extend first or second.

If you expand first, third goes to the right. If you expand second, third goes down.

Is there any way to keep it as it is on beginning?

Only thing i have figured out, is to keep them in two separate divs, but problem is that I am using  and it will be hard to split results to two groups;

Comment: Have you tried some of the proposed solutions?

Comment: Yes, and I think, all of them does not pass perfectly to my project. I decided to split my div to 2 divs - left/right, split my collections of items to even/odd and build it separately.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/foboqoxi/1

Change your second class="item" to class="item2".

```
.item2 {
   float: right;
  clear: right;
  width:45%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

and add a clear left in class="item"

```
.item
{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width:45%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="item2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-01c6530e-007e-4553-98a7-e7bd0273d3cf">
            <div class="heading">
                Second
            </div>
            <span class="icon"><span class="caret-big caret-down"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-01c6530e-007e-4553-98a7-e7bd0273d3cf" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body alternative">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="name">
                        aa
                    </div>
                    <div class="value">
                        Second
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="name">
                        aa
                    </div>
                    <div class="value">
                        Second
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, use the grid system from bootstrap:

i added rows and gave every item a column class:

http://jsbin.com/vebaluwo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Works good, however the 2nd one still doesn't work as to how OP wants. The third one shouldn't move down when you click the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .ic{position:relative;width:500px; hieght:100px; }

   .item{width:240px;position:relative;z-index:10;}

   .item:last-child{width:100%;position:absolute;z-index:1;top:30px;}
```